# PySpark - Assign values to previous data depending of last occurence

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an Apache PySpark Dataframe similar to the following (date is `yyyy-mm-dd`)

```
| ID |  is_test  |    date    |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 10 |     0     | 2019-01-01 |
| 10 |     0     | 2019-01-05 |
| 10 |     1     | 2019-01-08 | <= Most recent
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-02 |
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-04 |
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-04 |
| 11 |     1     | 2019-03-08 | <= Most recent
| 12 |     0     | 2019-06-08 |
| 12 |     0     | 2019-06-12 | <= Most recent
```

The objective is to create a new value and assign a same value for each ID depending of the last (most recent) row of each ID

So something like

```
| ID |  is_test  |    date    |    is_ok   |
|----|-----------|------------|------------|
| 10 |     0     | 2019-01-01 |      1     |
| 10 |     0     | 2019-01-05 |      1     |
| 10 |     1     | 2019-01-08 |      1     | 
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-02 |      1     |
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-04 |      1     |
| 11 |     0     | 2019-03-04 |      1     |
| 11 |     1     | 2019-03-08 |      1     | 
| 12 |     0     | 2019-06-08 |      0     |
| 12 |     0     | 2019-06-12 |      0     |
```

So basically for a given ID, when the last is 1, everyones before and same ID are also 1 and if the last if 0, everyone before (same ID too) is also zero.

I tried something with :

`partition = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(F.col("date"))` and I'm pretty sure this is a good start but can make it too the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use the last function to achieve this. here is the code

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([[10,0,"2019-01-01"],[10,0,"2019-01-05"],[10,1,"2019-01-08"],[11,0,"2019-03-02"],[11,0,"2019-03-04"],[11,0,"2019-03-04"],[11,1,"2019-03-08"],[12,0,"2019-06-08"],[12,0,"2019-06-12"]],["ID","is_test","_date"])
>>> df.show()
+---+-------+----------+
| ID|is_test|     _date|
+---+-------+----------+
| 10|      0|2019-01-01|
| 10|      0|2019-01-05|
| 10|      1|2019-01-08|
| 11|      0|2019-03-02|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|
| 11|      1|2019-03-08|
| 12|      0|2019-06-08|
| 12|      0|2019-06-12|
+---+-------+----------+

>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as func
>>> win = Window.partitionBy(df['ID']) .orderBy(df['date'].desc()) 
>>> df.withColumn("test",func.last('is_test').over(win)).show()
+---+-------+----------+----+
| ID|is_test|     _date|test|
+---+-------+----------+----+
| 10|      0|2019-01-01|   1|
| 10|      0|2019-01-05|   1|
| 10|      1|2019-01-08|   1|
| 12|      0|2019-06-08|   0|
| 12|      0|2019-06-12|   0|
| 11|      0|2019-03-02|   1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|   1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|   1|
| 11|      1|2019-03-08|   1|
+---+-------+----------+----+
```

I think that's what you are looking for.let me know if you have any questions related to the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that but are you sure this is not "orderBy('date')"  and also 'ascending' ?

Answer (score 1):

solution using `row_number` and two joins

```
  val df1 = df.select('*, row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('date)).as("rn"))
  val df2 = df1.groupBy('id).agg(max('rn).as("rn"))
  val df3 = df1.join(df2,Seq("id","rn"),"inner").select('id,'is_test.as("is_ok"))
  val df4 = df.join(df3,Seq("id"),"left")
  df4.show()
```

output:

```
+---+-------+----------+-----+
| id|is_test|      date|is_ok|
+---+-------+----------+-----+
| 10|      0|2019-01-01|    1|
| 10|      0|2019-01-05|    1|
| 10|      1|2019-01-08|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-02|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|    1|
| 11|      1|2019-03-08|    1|
| 12|      0|2019-06-08|    0|
| 12|      0|2019-06-12|    0|
+---+-------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just need to define [`rowsBetween`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween) with `Window.unboundedFollowing` like below and you will be all set.

```
win_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("is_ok", f.last('is_test').over(win_spec)).orderBy('ID').show()
+---+-------+----------+-----+
| ID|is_test|      date|is_ok|
+---+-------+----------+-----+
| 10|      1|2019-01-08|    1|
| 10|      0|2019-01-01|    1|
| 10|      0|2019-01-05|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-02|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|    1|
| 11|      0|2019-03-04|    1|
| 11|      1|2019-03-08|    1|
| 12|      0|2019-06-08|    0|
| 12|      0|2019-06-12|    0|
+---+-------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this one ! Just a question, what is the purpose of "rowsBetween" ?
I did it without and it seems to work too

Comment: Hi @LaSul  - rowsBetween defines window start and end to scan for applied function on window. If we don’t define rowsBetween and ask for last value then it will give value of same row. In your example, partition the data by ID column and order it by date column so now if you want last value on order by column( date) , it has to travers till end of the window and that’s where rowsBetween with unbounded following helps. UnboundedFollowing means that go till end of the specified partitioned window range.

Comment: @LaSul Check this link for visual representation of this concept : https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html